# Parent's coordinates changed after assigning a child

Tags: unity-game-engine

I need to make a pivot for a gun so i have to rotate it but after assigning child (gun) to a parent (pivot) pivot's coordinates visually changed but in fact they still the same. With that I can't rotate the gun correctly

Here's the pic of pivot before assigning:
[image: pic of pivot before assigning]
before:
[image: before assigning]
so when I try to rotate pivot it rotates not in the way I want it to:
[image: result]

Comment: Toggle the handle position from `center` to `pivot`.  It is at the top next to the tool icons on the left.